# How do I pass a variable containing a value to another page via a link (in <a> tag ) in PHP using the functionality of GET method

Tags: php, html

Hope you are having an excellent day :)
I'm learning to build my website,it's just a beginning.

```
$product_id=10;
echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td>Rs/-" . $sum . "</td><td><a href='success.php?id='$product_id'' class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a></td></tr>";
```

Now, in this code, I've been trying to pass the value of $product_id variable to my success.php page but the page receives null when I access the value, so, **How do I pass this value to my success.php page using the variable.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your single quotes are causing the `href` attribute to end at `id=`. Investigate the HTML in your browser, you'll see something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td>Rs/-1.23</td>
  <td>
    <a href='success.php?id=' $product_id'' class='btn btn-primary'>
      Confirm Order
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I recommend using curly braces to place variables inside of quoted content:

```
echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td>Rs/-{$sum}</td><td><a href='success.php?id={$product_id}' class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not correctly terminated the " that's why it not working fine. 
Following is the corrected code.

```
$product_id=10;
echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td>Rs/-" . $sum . "</td><td><a href='success.php?id=".$product_id."' class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a></td></tr>";
```

You can also use like @Charlie-Schliesser suggested. Both are correct.